# Fast way to tell if this matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have to say if this matrix is diagonalizable on the real numbers:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \ 
\ \ \ \ \ A\in \mathbb{R}^{3x3} $$

So i calculated the characteristic polynomial of $A$ as:

$$P(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1-\lambda & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & -\lambda \\ \end{vmatrix}=-\lambda^3+\lambda^2+5\lambda-1$$

Now to go on i needed to solve the equation $-\lambda^3+\lambda^2+5\lambda-1=0$ for $\lambda$ to get the eigenvalues of $A$, which i wasn't able to do by hand, so plugged the equation into WolframAlpha to see the intermediate steps, **but they are insane!** ([See the equation on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%5Clambda%5E3%2B%5Clambda%5E2%2B5%5Clambda-1%3D0))

I think i must be missing something because **i should be able to solve this exercise in 3 minutes**, since it comes from a linear algebra test made of 10 questions that has to be done in 30 minutes.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This matrix is symmetric

Comment: i know @clark, but according to my book a **real** symmetric matrix **might** be diagonalizable, hence i have to do further investigations to prove it. Am i wrong?

Comment: It's real symmetric and hence diagonalizable. More generally, check if it is normal.

Comment: A symmetric and real matrix is always diagonalizable

Comment: ok, thanks everybody

Comment: I gave an answer using the fact that a matrix is diagonalizable when it's characteristic polynomial has distinct roots, I hope that is something that we can use.

Comment: If a matrix's a characteristic equation has distinct roots then it is diagonalizable  but the other way is not true- a diagonalizable matrix does **not** have to have to have distinct characteristic roots.  But it **does** have to have a "complete set of Eigen**vectors**". That is, a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if there exist a basis for the vector space consisting of eigenvectors of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable.

Alternatively it suffices to show that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of the form $p_{A}(\lambda) = -(\lambda - r_1)(\lambda - r_2)(\lambda - r_3)$ where $r_i$ are distinct.

In our case $p_{A}(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+\lambda^2+5\lambda-1$. Now, $p_{A}(0)=-1,p_{A}(1)=4$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem $p_A$ has at least one root in each of the intervals $(-\infty,0), (0,1),(1,\infty) $, and since $p_A$ has degree $3$, $p_A$ has distinct roots.

Answer (score 2):

If you really just need a yes/no answer, I suppose you have that.

ADDED: this ($P^T H P = D$) can also be done with just integers, this time.

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & -1 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  -  1  &  1  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-1 &  - 1 &  - 1  \\ 
1 & 0 & 1   \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1   \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

For symmetric real matrices, there is another definition of "diagonalize" that does not use eigenvalues; given symmetric $H,$ we solve $P^T H P = D,$ with $D$ diagonal, and $\det P = \pm 1.$ This is often called repeated completing the square. Maybe I should add that the original and the diagonal matrix here are called "congruent" (or in some cases "equivalent") rather than "similar."

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$